# '[L' prefix in Java reflection

Tags: java, arrays, reflection

Using Java6 reflection API, `Class.getDeclaredFields` returns pretty weird values. Example of class field:

```
protected String[] arrF = new String[15];
```

Using `getDeclaredFields` on proper `Class`, a `Field` is returned:

- name = `arrF`
- type = `[Ljava.lang.String;`

The question: does `[L` prefix mean that the `arrF` is an array? Can I always rely on that, i.e. the field is an array iff type is prefixed with `[L`? If no, how can I get some information about "arrayness" of the field?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`[` means one-dimension array (`[[` is 2 dimensions array), and `L` followed by the class/interface name (`Lclassname`) is the type of that array.

- See [`Class#getName()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName--).

> Can I always rely on that, i.e. the field is an array iff type is prefixed with [L?

Yes. Or better, use [`Class#isArray()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isArray--).

Comment: Oh, I see. However, to get the dimension of the array, I need to parse the string to get count of the `[`, right? `Class` has no method doing that for me.

Comment: @petrbel See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764339/multi-dimension-length-array-reflection-java

Answer (score 2):

This is a much better way to do it!

```
    import java.lang.reflect.Field;
    import java.lang.reflect.Type;
    import static java.lang.System.out;

    public class ArrayFind {
        public static void main(String... args) {
             try {
                Class<?> cls = Class.forName(args[0]);
                Field[] flds = cls.getDeclaredFields();
                for (Field f : flds) {
                    Class<?> c = f.getType();
                    if (c.isArray()) {
                        // ....
                    }
                }

            } catch (ClassNotFoundException x) {
                x.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Btw. byte[] has name [B - [L is there for longs and/or references.

Answer (score 1):

**What you got is so called binary name.** Binary name is able to represent an array type as arrays in Java do not implement or extend an Array-like interface.

`[Ljava.lang.String;` means:

1. `[` single dimensional array
2. `L` array of reference types and not primitives
3. `java.lang.String;` represents the component type of the array